# Matplotlib: plotting curves with histogram data

Tags: matplotlib, line, histogram, curve

Currently have 3 sets of data in a single histogram, but I need to plot a single curve for each set of data. Currently plotting histograms through a function:

```
def plot_histogram(xmin,xmax,title,xlabel,data,data1,data2):
    plt.xlim(xmin, xmax)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency')
    bins=np.histogram(np.hstack((data,data1,data2)), bins=11)[1]
    plt.hist([data, data1, data2], bins, normed=1, alpha=0.5, color=['b', 'g', 'r'], label=['t', 'g-', 'g+'])
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.show()
```

How can I plot a curve or line which follows the shape of each histogram?

Comment: You may want to have a look at kernel density estimation (KDE). in my opinion `pandas` is the easiest way to plot `KDE`s.

Comment: I've been looking into KDEs and I've found this resource which should help (http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/examples/plotting_distributions.ipynb)  but unfortunately seaborn won't install on my computer.

Do you have any other pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a kde did give me the plot I wanted, but in fact I would suggest using `seaborn` for this, as the module has a command `distplot` which plots a histogram and density plot at the same time.

Examples of using seaborn given here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/examples/plotting_distributions.ipynb